# Connect express with react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I want to create simple react app with express server.

I have setup simple express server like following.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "hometask1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "webpack": "^4.26.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.4.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000/"
}
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

//app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}!`))

app.get('/express_backend', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ express: 'YOUR EXPRESS BACKEND IS CONNECTED TO REACT' });
  });
```

I have folder structure like:

```
projectfolder    
    node_modules
    index.html
    index.js
    package.json
    package-lock.json
```

Now, i want to connect this **express.js** with my react app. Following is my react app. (I don't want to use create-react-app)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/babel">

    var helloWorld = React.createElement("h1", {}, 'Hello World!');

    class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
        render () {
            return (
                    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
                )
        }
    }

    const container = React.createElement("div", {}, helloWorld, <HelloWorld /> );  

    ReactDOM.render(container, document.getElementById('root'))
</script>

</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with `connect` your `express` server with your `react app`? Do you want `express` to serve your html files, or do you want your frontend app to call the backend endpoints?

Comment: I want to express to serve html file. when i run localhost it should run index.html react app.

Comment: ok. I think `connect` is not really a good term. it could mean several things. But in that case, the first answer is correct then.

Comment: Ok thanks let me try then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to serve your files from a public dir on base URL request (http://domain/)

#### 1. Make css, jss files publicly accessible

Add this line to your express server file

```
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.use(express.static('public')) // this line
```

#### 2. Move `index.html` and `index.js` to `public` dir

You dir structure will look like

```
projectfolder    
    node_modules
    public
        index.html
        index.js
    package.json
    package-lock.json
```

#### 3. Add a route to serve the index file

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: 3. is not necessary, `express.static` does serve `index.html` on the root

Comment: you also need to add `const path = require('path');` that line to index.js

Comment: yes you dont actually need a `public` folder. It is a common practice, but not needed to serve a `html file`. the name of the folder could be anything you want too.